# withTimeout() function is not stopping my calculation within stipulated time

Tags: r

Let say I have below function (just an example, I have some other meaningful function in my actual R calculation)

```
library(R.utils)
    My_Fn = function() {
                Some_Try = 
                    try({
                        withTimeout({
                            Sys.sleep(30)
                        }, timeout = 10, onTimeout = "error")
                    }, silent = TRUE)
                    if (class(Some_Try) == 'try-error') {
                            XXX = 2
                        } else {
                            XXX = 3
                        }
                return(XXX)
            }
```

When I evaluate this function, I want this function should be forcefully stopped in 10s. But it is not happening in my case, It is stopping only after 30s as below -

```
> system.time(My_Fn())
   user  system elapsed 
  0.033   0.015  30.029
```

Can you please help me to figure out how to make my function to stop after 10s?

Please find my Session-info below -

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] R.utils_2.9.1     R.oo_1.23.0       R.methodsS3_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

When I looked into the examples associated with `withTimeout()` function, I observed strange behaviour -

**Below is stopping in ~1s**

```
foo <- function() {
  print("Tic")
  for (kk in 1:100) {
    print(kk)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }
  print("Tac")
}

system.time({
tryCatch({
  res <- withTimeout({
    foo()
  }, timeout = 1.08)
}, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
  message("Timeout. Skipping.")
})
})
```

**But, below is stopping only in 10s**

```
foo <- function() {
  print("Tic")
  for (kk in 1:100) {
    print(kk)
    Sys.sleep(10.1)
  }
  print("Tac")
}

system.time({
tryCatch({
  res <- withTimeout({
    foo()
  }, timeout = 1.08)
}, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
  message("Timeout. Skipping.")
})
})
```

**I was expecting the both examples above would stop in ~1.1s**, as defined by the parameter `timeout = 1.08`. Then, why the difference? Is there any bug in `withTimeout()` function?

Comment: Function works fine for me on Windows 10

Comment: @Khaynes  - Is it stopping after 10s?

Comment: It also works for me on a Mac. 10 seconds.

Comment: @ErrorJordan - I have added my sessionInfo() in my original post. I rechecked again, it still stopping only after 30s. I also checked in my Mac machine, and there also it is stopping in 30s

Comment: @Bogaso - my `sessionInfo()` looks almost identical. I'm not sure I understand it myself.

Comment: @Bogaso, yes it is stopping at 10.

Comment: @Khaynes - it is strange